Stripe integration with ajax request
I am integrating stripe. Strip3 integration is working fine i received the card token too. But facing issue in passing the token to controller from view page. In this application they have written common ajax call for all the forms. whenever i am  trying to append the  stripe token to form and passing value is not working in ajax. In Normal post method which is working fine. But i need to pass it in ajax which written commonly .
`
$(document).ready(function() {

        // Create an instance of Stripe
        var stripe = Stripe('{{ env('STRIPE_PUBLISH_KEY') }}');
        
        // Create an instance of elements
        var elements = stripe.elements();
        // Create a card element and add it to the DOM
       // var card = elements.create('card');
        //card.mount('#card-element');
        var cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber');
        cardNumber.mount('#example3-card-number');

        var cardExpiry = elements.create('cardExpiry');
        cardExpiry.mount('#example3-card-expiry');

        var cardCvc = elements.create('cardCvc');
        cardCvc.mount('#example3-card-cvc');
        // Handle form submission
       
        $(' #next').click(function(event) {
            $('#token').val(' ');
          //  event.preventDefault();

            stripe.createToken(cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    // Display error message to the user
                    var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;

                    // Re-enable the submit button
                    form.querySelector('button').disabled = false;
                    console.log(result.error);
                    return false;
                } else {
                   
                    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                    return false;
                   
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
      
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the     server
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

        // Add Stripe Token to hidden input
        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken1');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);

        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
        $('#token').val(token);
        var $form = $('#payment-form');
      $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));


        $form.get(0).submit(); // here it needs to continue the submit but passing it in post wrongly
       return true;
       
    }


Hey
You are using an old integration, I strongly encourage you to migrate using Stripe Element :
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/quickstart?platform=web&client=html
